# Design question POCO objects / DAL access

Tags: .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern, poco

i would like to implement the typical three layer architecture. My current approach looks as follows

- DAL - with EF 4.0 and repositories for each of my entities. access through interfaces
- I was thinking of using POCO objects. My first question would be where should i put those 
  files? In an assembly which is referenced by all other projects?
- BLL - How do i get the data from the DAL to the BLL and then finally to the GUI
  Is it a good way if i would have a whole bunch of manager classes there like CustomerManager in the BLL. These classes would access the corresponding repository in the BLL and then pass the objects to the GUI

Or do you think it is better to put the repository in the BLL and access them directly from my say buttoneventhandler?

Hopefully you can bring some light into the darkness

Comment: If one of our answers helped, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 6):

We have the repos in the DAL. The BLL references the repositories via an interface - so the repositories are tied to the DAL but decoupled from the BLL. I don't know of any reason why the repositories couldn't be directly in the BLL. We've got them in the DAL as we don't put ANY logic in them. We then have "Managers" in the BLL which wrap the repositories and handle entity-specific logic.

FWIW we actually have a generic `Repository(Of IEntity)` and use unity to instantiate the appropriate repository as required - it's very compact and quite elegant. All our POCO entities implement IEntity which contains `Id`, `CreatedDate`, etc. which are common to ALL our entities. This gives some other benefits when you need to handle any type of entity generically - `CreatedDate` is set by the repository when `CreateInstance()` is called, `ModifiedDate` is set by the context itself when it commits an entity with a state of `Modified`

We keep entities in a separate project - The DAL needs to be able to reference them, as does the BLL. You don't want them in the DAL as swapping the DAL out would cause issues. You can't put them in the BLL or you get a circular reference. Configuration for the entities can live in the DAL as it's data source-specific.

We try to stick to the BLL taking in primitives and returning entities. Be careful about keeping entities in the UI for too long, especially in a web app as you may have a different context under the DAL by the time you return the entity to the BLL for processing (ie across requests stored in session or similar) this can result in all kinds of fun attaching/detaching entities from contexts and loses you some benefits like change tracking.

Hope that helps but if you want any clarification, let me know

Comment: Actually no, we again use unity/dependency injection to return a reference to a single instance. This is because the managers depend upon repos which in turn depend upon the context which isn't static. You could probably work around this but we haven't.

Comment: One more trivial question. What is your recommendation in terms of naming. Do you use something like CustomerManager or like RPM1984 wrote CustomerService?

Comment: What we tend to use is "Manager" for something which interacts with only 1 entity Eg CustomerManager. We use "Service" for more complex multi-entity functionality - Eg MembershipService which interacts with a UserManager, RoleManager, etc - This again allows us to make our managers almost identical copies. The managers handle instantiation, updating, etc. of their own entities. In our Db, calling Delete on an entity simply changes a record status to "Inactive". The manager determines if the current user is allowed access to the deleted entities... Cont v

Comment: If not, it tacks a "AND RecordStatus <> Inactive" on to all queries as they are passed through to the repository. This allows services to simply call Manager.Get() and only retrieve the appropriate records.

Comment: Oh and BTW - your setup is very similar to ours. We also use `IRepository<T>` and inject a `GenericRepository<T>` via StructureMap. The only thing different is we don't have our entities inheriting from IEntity, because then they arent really POCO's. They're not tied to persistence per-se, but the fact of "Updating the datetime" (a problem i have with POCOs), is a database concern, so hence my point of losing the whole POCO. I still haven't figured out how to update datetime. I have three options - 1) trigger(yuck), 2) savechanges delegate (yuck), or 3) BLL (likely)

Comment: Oh and one other difference - you say "we use Manager for something that interacts with only 1 entity". We don't do that - we have one repository per aggregates root - in other words, we have a "PostRepository" which retrieves "Post", "Comment", "Likes", etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is our setup:

```
Company.Project.Domain.Model      (POCOs)
Company.Project.Business.Services (BLL)
Company.Project.Data.Repositories (Repository)
Company.Project.Web               (Presentation)
```

- POCO's are in their own assembly. *References nothing*, and *Referenced by all*.
- BLL execute queries against repositories, apply business rules and hydration. ***Returns `ICollection<T>` or `T`***. *References Repositories (via `IRepository<T>` generic interface) and POCOs*.
- Repository is set of generic classes implementing `IRepository<T>` to provide basic persistence against underlying store. Find, Add, Remove, etc. **Returns `IQueryable`**. *References POCO's*, *Referenced by BLL*.
- Presentation is UI. *References POCOs and BLL*.

The end result is a like stack-like approach, and because basically everything is via interfaces (and DI registries), the flexibility is enormous.

We have Mock Repositories which get injected into the test projects via DI, and Entity Framework Repositories which get injected into the BLL via DI.

Example flow from UI -> DB:

```
// "Company.Project.Web.ProductsController.cs"
public class ProductsController : BaseController
{
   private IProductService _productService;

   public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
   {
      this._productService = productService; // DI makes me happy :)
   }

   public ActionResult GetOrdersForProduct(Product product)
   {
      var orders = _productService.GetOrders(product);
      return View(orders);
   }
}

// "Company.Project.Business.Services.ProductService.cs"
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
   private IRepository<Product> _productRepository;

   public ProductService (IRepository<Product> productRepository)
   {
      this._productRepository = productRepository; // DI makes me happy :)
   }

   public ICollection<Orders> GetOrdersForProduct(Product product)
   {
      return _productRepository
                .Find()
                .ForProduct(product) // IQueryable<Product> pipe/extension filter
                .ToList();
   }
}

// "Company.Project.Data.Repositories.GenericRepository.cs
public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
   private IObjectSet<T> _objectSet;

   public GenericRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
   {
      CurrentContext = unitOfWork as SqlServerUnitOfWork;
   }

   public IQueryable<T> Find()
   {
      return CurrentContext.GetEntitySet<T>();
   }

   protected SqlServerUnitOfWork CurrentContext { get; private set; }

   protected IObjectSet<T> CurrentEntitySet
   {
      // some plularization smarts in "SqlServerUnitofWork.cs", to dynamically pull
      // back entity set based on T.
      get { return _objectSet ?? (_objectSet = CurrentContext.GetEntitySet<T>()); }
   }
}
```

As you can see, i am a DI fanboy.

Comment: Just a performance suggestion - Instead of returning ICollection<T> try returning IQueryable<T> - This allows you to Lazy load the items in the list reducing overhead if the UI only needs s subset (eg for paging)

Comment: @Basiclife - read my part about the Repository. I am doing exactly that. IMO they should be deferred to the BLL, not further down to the UI, otherwise one you could get unexpected results. Paging is easy, just pass the pagenumber/pagesize to the method in the BLL, which skip/takes on the iqueryable from the repo.

Comment: And by the way, that is not lazy loading, that is **deferred execution**. Be careful not to confuse the two. I disable lazy loading in EF, and eager load the entities the BLL requires using `.Include`.

Comment: @RPM1984, do you hand-write your POCOs or you're generating them using the EF4 POCO Generator?

Comment: A bit of both. :) If generating a model from an existing DB, i use the generator, then copy the code into the classes in my seperate assembly. Good to do this way, because EF POCO is very much convention-based. If you mispell a property when hand-coding, you will get a (not so obvious) error.

Comment: @RPM1984 - 100% right re: deferred - I should think before posting @3am :) We've tended to put paging in the UI category rather than the BL but I can see your reasoning.

Comment: @RPM1984 We also disable lazy loading as it allows the UI to bypass the BLL and navigate the entire db unrestricted

Comment: @Basiclife - exactly, that's why i only defer to the service. I've implemented an experimentral BLL, kind of like the spec pattern. It takes a generic `Expression<Func<T,bool>>` predicate to do the filtering on the `IQueryable<T>`. This allows minimimum maintenance and maximum flexbility (but not for everyone - UI coders with sticky fingers could do `s => s.Id > 0` and return all the records. But then again i trap that with special covering overloads and max `Take`. And BTW - with paging, there are great implementations of `PagedList<T>` out there which do the paging nicely. (i use Rob Cons)

Comment: @RPM1984, where would objects that display behavior go? e.g. I have a TrackingScript object that gets used by a helper class. It has a few properties that have getter logic in them.

Comment: @Praveen - can you clarify what you mean by "objects that display behaviour"? What type of objects/logic?

Comment: If your talking about UI stuff then that goes in the web tier (or the "common.mvc.ui" assembly which is shared amongst projects)

Comment: e.g. Say I have a ContentManager class to display static content. The ContentManager works with an object ContentTag. Where would ContentTag go in your projects?

Comment: Sorry, im still confused if you mean HTML or something else - please give a specific example. What does ContentTag do? Is that a table?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep this really simple by keeping your repositories and POCOs in the same project. This would essentially be your Data Domain Model. Your POCOs are public and so are your repository interfaces. You should keep your concrete repositories internal to this project.

Your BLL could be a classic Facade or Service Locator. This project would massage your data and apply any relevant business rules before handing it over to the UI. This would also be responsible for validating data coming in from the UI before sending it over to the DAL.

Comment: Interesting approach. Where does your entity configuration live? ie SQL data types for properties, Indexes?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. All access to SQL would be abstracted away by your Data Model (.edmx).

Comment: Ah okay - We use EF4 code-first so our entities are classes we create by hand and we manually craft our configurations (keys, FKs, etc.) this means we can keep the SQL-specific stuff like data types tied to the DAL but have the POCO entities generic.